# How to use label and pageref inside titleformat to show chapter with each section (but only once a page)

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, page-numbering, titlesec

For aesthetic reasons, I'm trying to repeat the chapter name before a section, but only if the chapter referencing is not on the same page, and no previous section on the same page is referencing to the chapter.

In short:
page 1:

> 1. First Chapter
>
> 1.1 First Section
>
> 1.2 Second Section

page 2:

> First Chapter
>
> 1.3 Third Section
>
> 1.4 Fourth Section

I know that using `\thepage` is not the correct way to do it, and that
`\pageref` is preferred, but I can't get this to work. Apart from the `\thepage` being incorrect on the second page, the following does work, but will break very fast (as `\thepage` would not be correctly set on the second page, leaving it on the first page and not showing the chapter name):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{ifthen,xcolor}
\usepackage[small,sf,bf]{titlesec}

% get the text from the current chapter's title
\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark
\def\chaptermark#1{\def\Chaptername{#1}\Chaptermark{#1}}

\xdef\cp{\thepage} %define the page where the last chapter is
\xdef\sp{\thepage} %define the page where the last section is

\titleformat{\chapter}  %command
[block]                 %shape
{\huge\bfseries}        %format
{\thechapter}           %label
{0pt}                   %sep
{}                      %before-code
[\xdef\cp{\thepage}]    %after-code

% reformat \section
\titleformat{\section}
[block]
{\huge\bfseries}
{   % only show Chaptername once a page
    \ifthenelse{\cp = \thepage}%
    {}% if last chapter on same page, do nothing
    {
        \ifthenelse{\sp =  \thepage}%
        {}% if last section on same page, do nothing
        {\Chaptername \\} %show chapter name
    }
}
{0pt}
{}
[\xdef\sp{\thepage}]



\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
\lipsum
\section{Third Section}
\section{Fourth Section}
\end{document}
```

Using `\label{\Sectionname}` inside `\titleformat` for the section (`\Sectionname` analogue to `\Chaptername`) and then using `\pageref{\Sectionname}` instead of `\thepage` does not seems to work. (Nor does using a custom counter for both)

How can I properly use a reference to the page?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way with `\label{\Chaptername}` (hoping the chapter names are unique) and retrieving the page number with `\getpagerefnumber` from `refcount` package, comparing with `\ifnum...`.

Don't redefine `\sp` -- this macro has a special meaning in `TeX`

There were a lot of spurious spaces as well, I removed them.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[small,sf,bf]{titlesec}

\usepackage{refcount}

% get the text from the current chapter's title
\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark
\def\chaptermark#1{\def\Chaptername{#1}\Chaptermark{#1}}

\xdef\currentp{\thepage} %define the page where the last chapter is
\xdef\lastp{\thepage} %define the page where the last section is

\titleformat{\chapter}  %command
[block]                 %shape
{\huge\bfseries}        %format
{\thechapter\ }           %label
{0pt}                   %sep
{}                      %before-code
[\label{\Chaptername}\xdef\currentp{\thepage}]    %after-code

% reformat \section
\titleformat{\section}
[block]
{\huge\bfseries}
{% only show Chaptername once a page
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{\Chaptername}=\value{page}%
  \else
  \ifnum\lastp=\value{page}%  
  \else
  \Chaptername\ \\%
  \fi
  \fi
}%
{0pt}%
{}%
[\xdef\lastp{\thepage}]



\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
\lipsum
\section{Third Section}
\section{Fourth Section}
\clearpage
\section{Fifth Section}
\end{document}
```

[image]